# $F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ bounded and closed. Show that every continuous function $f: F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded and closed. Show that every continuous function $f: F \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

Attempt:

Supposing not, since $f$ is unbounded, for every $n$ natural one can find $x_n\in F$ such that $|f(x_n)|>n$. Therefore, we can consider the sequence $(x_n)$ in $F$ defined this way. Since $F$ is bounded, there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ which is convergent, say $a = \lim x_{n_k}$.

By the continuity of $f$ i can evaluate the limit $\lim f(x_{n_k}) = f(\lim x_{n_k}) = f(a).$ But how to proceed from here? Any help?

Comment: This is Weierstrass' theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are your two statements $|f(x_{n_k})| > n_k$ and $f(x_{n_k})\to f(x)$ as $n_k \to \infty$ consistent? As per MH's comment - you implicitly used the fact that $F$ is closed to deduce that $x = \lim{x_{n_k}} \in F$ and so $f(x)$ exists.

Comment: So obvious haha thank you, anyway

Comment: The poster did not use the fact that the domain is closed. That is used to show that $a = \lim_k x_{n_k}$ is in the domain.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks, I've added it in.

Answer (score 2):

The way you chose the sequence implies that $|f(x_{n_k})|\to\infty$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Is topology at your disposal?  $F$ closed and bounded means it's compact, so its image under $f$ is compact, thus bounded.  So, $f$ is bounded.